# How to append some strings in the log in the below code

Tags: java, logging, buffer

I want to make a log in the java code. And, the whole process takes hours to finish. But my code makes all the log at the end of the execution, because buffer is closed at the end.

Is there any method, so that I can append in the log file ?

Please see my code, and suggest some necessary changes. 
Thanks in advance.

**My code**,

```
public class test {

    public static void func(String url1, String url2, BufferedWriter bw) throws  InterruptedException, IOException {
        long loading_time = 10878;
        long parsing_time = 120;
        long processing_time = 329;
        Thread.sleep(100000000);  // Here is some process that performs recursively
        bw.write( url1 + "\n" + url2 + "\n"+ ((double)loading_time)/((double)1000)+ " seconds   " + ((double)parsing_time)/((double)1000) +  " seconds   "  + ((double)processing_time)/((double)1000) + " seconds\n\n\n\n" );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\jhamb\\Desktop\\log.txt");
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { func("hitesh", "jhamb", bw);  }
            bw.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Sorry some problem");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use any logging framework

Comment: @rajesh Please see my above code, and please suggest me how can I change this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add dependency of `log4j` in POM, for that copy below lines,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Then , make a file `log.properties` and copy these lines at the location `<PROJECT FOLDER>\src\main\resources\`

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=C:/Users/jhamb/Desktop/log.txt

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Then, add line in the main Class,

```
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger( Scroll_down.class.getName() );
```

Here, Scroll_down is Class name in my project.

Now you can make a log where ever you want by using

`log.info( <PUT STRING HERE> )`

Here in my above case it is ,

```
log.info( url1 + "\n" + url2 + "\n"+ ((double)loading_time)/((double)1000)+ " seconds   " + ((double)parsing_time)/((double)1000) +  " seconds   "  + ((double)processing_time)/((double)1000) + " seconds\n\n\n\n" );
```

These are the steps, that I followed to fulfill my requirement of above question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a logging framework to log rather than writing your own files
Take a look at [SL4J](http://www.slf4j.org/)

This is a Hello World sample from their site:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);
    logger.info("Hello World");
  }
}
```

Where ever you call a bw.write(), replace with a logger.info(), logger.warn() logger.error() etc as the case may be.

This will output to the console. You will have to use a config to indicate that you need this is a file.  I leave that to you :-)

Edit:

Your code, once you use sl4j will be:

```
public class Test {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test.class);
    public static void func(String url1, String url2, BufferedWriter bw) throws  InterruptedException, IOException {
        //your code
        logger.info(" {} \n {} \n  {} seconds   {} seconds   {}  seconds\n\n\n\n",url1,url2 ,((double)loading_time)/((double)1000),((double)parsing_time)/((double)1000), ((double)processing_time)/((double)1000) );

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        try {
               //
        } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Sorry some problem",e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But you have to use a framework to log rather than writing yourself. This will be one think that you will use in all your code.

Comment: File path will be based on your log config.

Comment: I seriously don't know anything about this, please tell me where the log config is ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use a blocking queue to store your log tasks. As soon as you have something to Log create a log object and store in the queue. (simple strings will also suffice)

A separate thread should concurrently process your queue.

For implementation details check out: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/blockingqueue_example.shtml

However long your procedure (recursive or otherwise) runs, your queue would be processed simultaneously and you don't need to wait for the entire process to end to begin logging.